# ListAdapter value is null in Async class even after declaring in onCreate

Tags: android

I debugged the whole program , the error is `mForecastAdapter` in `onPostExecution` is null , So any attempt to use `mForecastAdapter.clear()` is resulting in error , I cannot understand even mForecastAdapter is global variable and it is initialized in onCreate() function ,please help

**Code**

```
public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {

    private ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter=null;
    private List<String> weekForecast=null;
    private Context con;
    public ForecastFragment(){

    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        //con=getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        String[] forecastArray={
                "Mon 6/23 - Sunny -31/17",
                "Tue 6/24 - Foggy -21/8",
                "Wed 6/25 - Cloudy -22/17",
                "Thurs 6/26 - Rainy -18/11",
                "Fri 6/27 - Foggy -21/10",
                "Sat 6/28 - TRAPPED IN WEATHERSTATION -23/18",
                "Sun 6/29 - Sunny -31/17"};

        weekForecast=new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(forecastArray));
        mForecastAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.list_item_forecast,R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,forecastArray );
        ListView listview=(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
        listview.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);

        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String forecast=mForecastAdapter.getItem(position);
                callActivity(forecast);

            }
        });


        return rootView;
    }

    private void callActivity(String forecast) {
        Intent myIntent=new Intent(getActivity(), DetailedForecast.class).putExtra("INFORMATION",forecast);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }

    public class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String[]>{

        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {

            if(params.length==0){
                return null;
            }

            HttpURLConnection urlConnection=null;
            BufferedReader reader=null;

            String forecastJsonStr =null;
            String format="json";
            String units="metric";
            int numDays=7;

            try {

                final String FORECAST_BASE_URL="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?";
                final String QUERY_PARAM="q";
                final String FORMAT_PARAM="mode";
                final String UNITS_PARAM="units";
                final String DAYS_PARAM="cnt";

                Uri builtUri= Uri.parse(FORECAST_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                        .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM,params[0])
                        .appendQueryParameter(FORMAT_PARAM,format)
                        .appendQueryParameter(UNITS_PARAM,units)
                        .appendQueryParameter(DAYS_PARAM,Integer.toString(numDays))
                        .build();

                Log.i("ALEX",builtUri.toString());


                URL url =new URL(builtUri.toString());

                urlConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                InputStream inputStream=urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer=new StringBuffer();
                if(inputStream==null){
                    return null;
                }

                reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
                    buffer.append(line+"\n");
                }

                if(buffer.length()==0){
                    return  null;
                }

                forecastJsonStr=buffer.toString();

                Log.v("ALEX","JSON"+forecastJsonStr);

            } catch (MalformedURLException ee) {
                ee.printStackTrace();
            }catch (IOException ee){
                Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error ", ee);
            }finally {
                if(urlConnection!=null){
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }

                if(reader!=null){
                    try{
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (IOException ee) {
                        Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error closing stream", ee);
                    }
                }
            }

            try{
                return getWeatherDataFromJson(forecastJsonStr,numDays);
            }catch (JSONException e){
                Log.e("ALEX",e.getMessage(),e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

         //CODE FROM UDACITY STARTS
         private String getReadableDateString(long time){

             SimpleDateFormat shortenedDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd");
             return shortenedDateFormat.format(time);
         }
         //CODE FROM UDACITY ENDS

         private String[] getWeatherDataFromJson(String forecastJsonStr, int numDays) throws JSONException{

             final String OWM_LIST="list";
             final String OWM_WEATHER="weather";
             final String OWM_TEMP="temp";
             final String OWM_MAX="max";
             final String OWM_MIN="min";
             final String OWM_DESCRIPTION="main";

             JSONObject weather=new JSONObject(forecastJsonStr);
             JSONArray days=weather.getJSONArray(OWM_LIST);

             //CODE FROM UDACITY STARTS
             Time dayTime = new Time();
             dayTime.setToNow();
             int julianStartDay = Time.getJulianDay(System.currentTimeMillis(), dayTime.gmtoff);
             //CODE FROM UDACITY ENDS

             String[] resultStrs=new String[numDays];
             for(int i=0;i<days.length();i++){

                 String day="";
                 String description;
                 String highAndLow;

                 JSONObject dayForecast=days.getJSONObject(i);


                 //CODE FROM UDACITY STARTS
                 long dateTime;
                 dateTime = dayTime.setJulianDay(julianStartDay+i);
                 day = getReadableDateString(dateTime);
                 //CODE FROM UDACITY ENDS


                 JSONObject weatherObject=dayForecast.getJSONArray(OWM_WEATHER).getJSONObject(0);
                 description=weatherObject.getString(OWM_DESCRIPTION);


                 JSONObject temp=dayForecast.getJSONObject(OWM_TEMP);
                 double high=temp.getDouble(OWM_MAX);
                 double low=temp.getDouble(OWM_MIN);
                 //highAndLow=formatHighLows(high, low);

                 highAndLow=Double.toString(Math.round(high))+"/"+Double.toString(Math.round(low));


                 resultStrs[i]=day+" - "+description+" - "+highAndLow;

             }

             for (String s : resultStrs) {
                 Log.v("ALEX", "Forecast entry: " + s);
             }
             return resultStrs;


         }


        @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(String[] strings) {

            mForecastAdapter.clear();
            mForecastAdapter.addAll(strings);

         }
     }
}
```

This is the error, have a look on first line

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ArrayAdapter.clear()' on a null object reference
        at com.betatech.alex.sunshine.ForecastFragment$FetchWeatherTask.onPostExecute(ForecastFragment.java:269)
        at com.betatech.alex.sunshine.ForecastFragment$FetchWeatherTask.onPostExecute(ForecastFragment.java:89)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
```

Comment: best option is  manaually clear adapter by creating clear method in your adapter class... call from onpost...

Comment: In onPost the adapter variable is having null value ,.....................I haven't made any custom adapter class , The initial dummy string "forecastArray={"Mon 6/23..."...}" are getting properly initialized but after getting JSON data I want to fill my listview with new data , and thats the problem

Comment: after clear() you need to call Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() if you are using Array adapter

Comment: Please try to understand that the value of listAdapter in onPostExecute is null , so I cannot use any function of listAdapter

Comment: From where are you invoking the asyncTask?

Comment: I am invoking it From MainActivity.java that uses a fragment "ForecastFragmnet.java" whose code is  provided above, the Async class is inside the ForecastFragment class ,

Comment: If possible, start the asyncTask from onActivityCreated() method of Fragment. This will make sure that your adapter is initialized.

Comment: I have a refresh button in my actionbar() in MainActivity.java which calls async , can i define this in my fragmentclass

Comment: Yes you can. Add it to menu of fragment and call setHasOptionsMenu(true)

Comment: I thnk you fragement is not in view whenever u are calling that Async task   .... Please check is that fragment is active when sync call made from Mainactivity...... fragment manager keeps limited number of Fragment active ....

Comment: @koutuk how to keep fragment active ??

Comment: if you are using viewpager ....use pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0); pass number of fragment you want to load during each transaction  ....

Answer (score 0):

In order to have your `ListView` update, you should update the array you provided to your adapter and call `adapter.notifyDataSetCHanged()`. The adapter will handle the rest for you.

i.e. You should make `forecastArray` global (declare it at the top of your class), then in your `onPostExecute()` you can do the following:

```java
             @Override
             protected void onPostExecute(String[] strings) {

               forecastArray = strings;
               mForecastAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

             }
```

Let me know if this helps, or if you need more info.

EDIT: Here is the code for what I have been trying to explain to you in the comments.

```java
public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {

    private ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter;
    private List<String> weekForecast=null;
    private Context con;
    ListView listview;
    public ForecastFragment(){

    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        //con=getActivity().getApplicationContext();

        listview=(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);


        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String forecast=mForecastAdapter.getItem(position);
                callActivity(forecast);

            }
        });


        return rootView;
    }

    private void callActivity(String forecast) {
        Intent myIntent=new Intent(getActivity(), DetailedForecast.class).putExtra("INFORMATION",forecast);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }

    public class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String[]> {

        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {

            if(params.length==0){
                return null;
            }

            HttpURLConnection urlConnection=null;
            BufferedReader reader=null;

            String forecastJsonStr =null;
            String format="json";
            String units="metric";
            int numDays=7;

            try {

                final String FORECAST_BASE_URL="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?";
                final String QUERY_PARAM="q";
                final String FORMAT_PARAM="mode";
                final String UNITS_PARAM="units";
                final String DAYS_PARAM="cnt";

                Uri builtUri= Uri.parse(FORECAST_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                        .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM,params[0])
                        .appendQueryParameter(FORMAT_PARAM,format)
                        .appendQueryParameter(UNITS_PARAM,units)
                        .appendQueryParameter(DAYS_PARAM,Integer.toString(numDays))
                        .build();

                Log.i("SANJEEV", builtUri.toString());


                URL url =new URL(builtUri.toString());

                urlConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                InputStream inputStream=urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer=new StringBuffer();
                if(inputStream==null){
                    return null;
                }

                reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
                    buffer.append(line+"\n");
                }

                if(buffer.length()==0){
                    return  null;
                }

                forecastJsonStr=buffer.toString();

                Log.v("SANJEEV_TAG","JSON"+forecastJsonStr);

            } catch (MalformedURLException ee) {
                ee.printStackTrace();
            }catch (IOException ee){
                Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error ", ee);
            }finally {
                if(urlConnection!=null){
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }

                if(reader!=null){
                    try{
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (IOException ee) {
                        Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error closing stream", ee);
                    }
                }
            }

            try{
                return getWeatherDataFromJson(forecastJsonStr,numDays);
            }catch (JSONException e){
                Log.e("SANJEEV",e.getMessage(),e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        //CODE FROM UDACITY STARTS
        private String getReadableDateString(long time){

            SimpleDateFormat shortenedDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd");
            return shortenedDateFormat.format(time);
        }
        //CODE FROM UDACITY ENDS

        private String[] getWeatherDataFromJson(String forecastJsonStr, int numDays) throws JSONException{

            final String OWM_LIST="list";
            final String OWM_WEATHER="weather";
            final String OWM_TEMP="temp";
            final String OWM_MAX="max";
            final String OWM_MIN="min";
            final String OWM_DESCRIPTION="main";

            JSONObject weather=new JSONObject(forecastJsonStr);
            JSONArray days=weather.getJSONArray(OWM_LIST);

            //CODE FROM UDACITY STARTS
            Time dayTime = new Time();
            dayTime.setToNow();
            int julianStartDay = Time.getJulianDay(System.currentTimeMillis(), dayTime.gmtoff);
            //CODE FROM UDACITY ENDS

            String[] resultStrs=new String[numDays];
            for(int i=0;i<days.length();i++){

                String day="";
                String description;
                String highAndLow;

                JSONObject dayForecast=days.getJSONObject(i);


                //CODE FROM UDACITY STARTS
                long dateTime;
                dateTime = dayTime.setJulianDay(julianStartDay+i);
                day = getReadableDateString(dateTime);
                //CODE FROM UDACITY ENDS


                JSONObject weatherObject=dayForecast.getJSONArray(OWM_WEATHER).getJSONObject(0);
                description=weatherObject.getString(OWM_DESCRIPTION);


                JSONObject temp=dayForecast.getJSONObject(OWM_TEMP);
                double high=temp.getDouble(OWM_MAX);
                double low=temp.getDouble(OWM_MIN);
                //highAndLow=formatHighLows(high, low);

                highAndLow=Double.toString(Math.round(high))+"/"+Double.toString(Math.round(low));


                resultStrs[i]=day+" - "+description+" - "+highAndLow;

            }

            for (String s : resultStrs) {
                Log.v("SANJEEV", "Forecast entry: " + s);
            }
            return resultStrs;


        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String[] strings) {


            mForecastAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.list_item_forecast,R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,strings );

            listview.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);


        }
    }
}
```

I threw this together as quick as I could, so if there are errors I am sorry. But, the parts to focus on are the declarations at the top of the class, some changes I made in `onCreateView()`, and the `onPostExecute()`.

Also, I urge you to be a bit less demanding and a bit more appreciative of the free help you are getting. If I weren't in such a good mood I probably would've (justifiably) told you to find help somewhere else after your last couple of comments.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()' on a null object reference

Comment: The value of arrayAdapter when accessed in inside Async class is null

Comment: Why don't you try initializing and setting the adapter in `onPostExecute()` instead?  Do you really need the dummy data?

Comment: Tried but after that i have to reinitialize ListView and that i cannot do outside as it requires findViewById and that I am not able to use in Async class

Comment: You don't have to reinitialize the listView! Just declare it at the top of the class, then you can initialize it just like you do now.. then just set the adapter in the `onPostExecute()`

Comment: I am tired , why don't you understand the value of Listadapter in onPostexecute is null even after being a global variable , so I cannot use any function provided by list adapter

Comment: It isn't null if you initialize it there.. I have written several apps with multiple activities/fragments that do exactly that. I will update my answer o show you what I am trying to explain.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81704/discussion-between-l-x-and-ryguy).

Answer (score 0):

**just put condition in post **

if (!mForecastAdapter.isempty()){

```
mForecastAdapter.clear()
```

}

Comment: Buddy I want to re initialize the array adapter and I know its value is null , this is not what I am looking for